# Google Map Directions.load fails, returns SERVER_ERROR

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, jakarta-ee

I'm trying out google directions from the gwt-map library.
Apart from assigning RootPanel in onModuleLoad(), I have copied most of the codes from SimpleDirectionsDemo.java.

I get a **"Failed to load directions: SERVER_ERROR"** message callback after running

```
Directions.load(query, opts, new DirectionsCallback() {

  public void onFailure(int statusCode) {
    Window.alert("Failed to load directions: Status "
        + StatusCodes.getName(statusCode) + " " + statusCode);
  }

  public void onSuccess(DirectionResults result) {
    GWT.log("Successfully loaded directions.", null);
  }
});
```

---

- API of GWT-Map Library:
  http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/index.html
- The working example can be found at 
  http://gwt.google.com/samples/hellomaps-1.1.0/HelloMaps.html#Simple%20Directions
- while the files can be found at
  http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmaps%2Fsamples%2Fhellomaps%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fmaps%2Fsample%2Fhellomaps%2Fclient%253Fstate%253Dclosed

*and here's a snippet of the working code thats found in the trunk..*

```
 public SimpleDirectionsDemo() {
    final Grid grid = new Grid(1, 2);
    grid.setWidth("100%");
    grid.getCellFormatter().setWidth(0, 0, "500px");
    grid.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 0,
        HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
    grid.getCellFormatter().setWidth(0, 1, "300px");
    grid.getCellFormatter().setVerticalAlignment(0, 1,
        HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_TOP);
    map = new MapWidget(LatLng.newInstance(42.351505, -71.094455), 15);
    map.setHeight("480px");
    grid.setWidget(0, 0, map);
    DirectionsPanel directionsPanel = new DirectionsPanel();
    grid.setWidget(0, 1, directionsPanel);
    directionsPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    initWidget(grid);

    DirectionQueryOptions opts = new DirectionQueryOptions(map, directionsPanel);
    String query = "from: 500 Memorial Dr, Cambridge, MA to: 4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA";
    Directions.load(query, opts, new DirectionsCallback() {

      public void onFailure(int statusCode) {
        Window.alert("Failed to load directions: Status "
            + StatusCodes.getName(statusCode) + " " + statusCode);
      }

      public void onSuccess(DirectionResults result) {
        GWT.log("Successfully loaded directions.", null);
      }
    });
  }
```

Anyone experienced with either google maps or gwt-map knows why does the load fail ?

Answer (score 0):

Realized on my end, I decided to leave out the DirectionsPanel.

My original code for DirectionQueryOptions was

```
DirectionQueryOptions opts = new DirectionQueryOptions(map);
```

which apparently causes SERVER_ERROR 
Based on the API at http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/index.html

There's an error with the api since it gives a constructor with just map as a parameter.
DirectionsPanel is mandatory to be declared if you're going to use gwt-map library

Correct code:

```
DirectionQueryOptions opts = new DirectionQueryOptions(map, directionsPanel);
```